# add conditional title="" to html with if statement angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Is it possible to contitionally add the title="" attribute to a div? i want to make it look clean so i dont want to create a second div and using ngIf to hide one or the other.

My div looks like this and it should add a title if `permission` is true

```
<div (click)="goToChangelog()" [ngStyle]="{'cursor': (permission) ? 'pointer' : ''}">
    Version {{version}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :

`[attr.title]="(permission) ? 'Go to Changelog' : ''"`

In this example, if the permission variable is true, the div will have a title attribute with the value "Go to Changelog". If permission is false, the title attribute will not be added to the div.

And here's the official doc : https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding